# Subsonic 3 T4 Templates - Output half of a View to a UserControl

Tags: visual-studio, subsonic, t4

I am using the Subsonic MVC Template and in the List.tt template it loops through all the properties and puts them into an HTML table.

I would like that table written to a usercontrol but after a few hours I cannot get it to work properly.

The T4 templates can be found here http://code.google.com/p/subsonicproject/downloads/list.

I can get stuff out to a seperate file but getting the whole table with properties out is proving difficult.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what difficulties your having?

Comment: My main problem is sending all the output it generates from the begin <table> and end </table> code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it so don't worry about it...